# Secure data like music , pictures and videos downloaded from webservice from end user access

Tags: android, security

I am building an android app, in which I am downloading contents like music,pictures and videos for recreational purposes. But, I dont want my end user to have access to these contents.
If I store these contents into sdcard, then the user can get easy access to these files.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could encrypt the content and decrypt it only when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. Users have full control over their Android devices and trying to hide/restrict information from the user is impossible. You can do things like encrypt the content, but your app would still need to have the decryption keys available so a dedicated user could reverse engineer your app to obtain the decryption key and then access the content.